# Isotope Images is not showing in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

The site i have made is at http://opplev.olavsfestdagene.no

It works as intended in everything except IE. None of the pictures is showing. Does anyone has any idea of what might be wrong?

It is html markup failure, or is it the isotope that is not working somehow?

[image]

Comment: Which IE have you tested it in?

Comment: All versions. The images seem to work the first time u load the page. Try refreshing if u got the pictures working the first time

Comment: Yea I refreshed the page and it's still loading from instagram and the other social networks...

Comment: Thanks :) See my edit for the problem i'm having. Its like that on several computers.

Comment: I've refreshed it several times in IE7, IE8 and IE9. I dont see the issue you are having! It could be the network you guys are on?

Comment: But why would it work in other browsers?

Comment: Good question. Maybe it's the Internet Explorer security settings you have, or your virus software? I dont have any security software and my internet explorer security settings are at the default.

Answer (score 0):

are you getting following error in IE debugger

SEC7112: Le script de http://raw.github.com/desandro/isotope/master/jquery.isotope.min.js a été bloqué à cause d'une incompatibilité de type mime

```
The script has been blocked due to mime type mismatch
```

You shouldn't be linking directly to raw.github.com. Fortunately, there's rawgithub.com to solve for that!

Try http://rawgithub.com/desandro/isotope/master/jquery.isotope.min.js